# Spring boot mongodb - No property found on class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I can't find the way to solve my problem in google. I am newbie in studying Spring Boot Integration With MongoDB. Here is my problems:

## **Code: **

**Product.java**

```
package com.example.SE.Collection;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "Product")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String ProductId;
    private String Category;
    private String Name;
    private double Cost;
    private String Description;
    private String How_to_use;
    private String Ingredient;
    private String Brand;
    private int Volume;
    private int Mark;
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
package com.example.SE.repository;

import com.example.SE.Collection.Product;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {
    List<Product> findByCategory(String Category);
}
```

**ProductServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.SE.service;

import com.example.SE.Collection.Product;
import com.example.SE.repository.ProductRepository;
import jdk.jfr.Category;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl{
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    public List<Product> allProduct() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Product> IdProduct(String ProductId){
        return productRepository.findById(ProductId);
    }

    public List<Product> CateProducts(String Category){
        return productRepository.findByCategory(Category);
    }
}
```

**ProductController.java**

```
package com.example.SE.controller;

import com.example.SE.Collection.Product;
import com.example.SE.service.ProductServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/Product")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceImpl productService;
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> GetAllProduct() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(productService.allProduct(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @GetMapping("/{ProductId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Product>> getId(@PathVariable("ProductId") String ProductId){
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Product>>(productService.IdProduct(ProductId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/Category/{Category}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getCateProducts(@PathVariable("Category") String Category){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(productService.CateProducts(Category), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

## **Log**

`org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'category' found on class com.example.SE.Collection.Product; Did you mean: Category,category at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.createPersistentPropertyPath(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.lambda$getPersistentPropertyPath$1(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:171) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.getPersistentPropertyPath(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.from(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.from(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:299) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:116) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.createQuery(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:85) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:134) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5] at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy73.findByCategory(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy73.findByCategory(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] at com.example.SE.service.ProductServiceImpl.CateProducts(ProductServiceImpl.java:26) ~[classes/:na] at com.example.SE.controller.ProductController.getCateProducts(ProductController.java:29) ~[classes/:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:188) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3] at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]`

I have tried to change the name of method findByCategory and variable Category but it doesn't work

Comment: Spring data follows convention. In java if you create entities, the field names should be in lowerCamelCase. In the repository when you call findByCategory it is looking for field category instead of Category